# Use imported Algebraic Data Type in eval

Tags: rascal

I'm using the `eval` function to evaluate an abstract list pattern against a list and it keeps coming up with an Undeclared Variable error. Below is included a small reproducible example.

```
module PuzzleScript::Test::Engine::EvalExample

import util::Eval;
import IO;

data Animal = dog() | cat();

void main(){    
    bool boolean = [*_, cat(), *_] := [dog(), cat()];
    if (boolean) println("True 1");
    
    println("[*_, cat(), *_] := [dog(), cat()];");
    Result[bool] re = eval(#bool, "[*_, cat(), *_] := [dog(), cat()];");
    if (re.val) println("True 2");

}
```

Which generates the following error

```
Rascal Version: 0.18.2, see |release-notes://0.18.2|
rascal>import PuzzleScript::Test::Engine::EvalExample;
ok
rascal>main()
True 1
[*_, cat(), *_] := [dog(), cat()];
|std:///util/Eval.rsc|(622,1030,<23,0>,<60,95>): StaticError(
  "Undeclared variable: dog\nAdvice: |http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Errors/Static/UndeclaredVariable/UndeclaredVariable.html|",
  |eval:///?command=[*_,%2520cat(),%2520*_]%20:=%20[dog(),%2520cat()];|(20,3,<1,20>,<1,23>))
        at $evalinstance$0(|main://$evalinstance$0|)
        at *** somewhere ***(|std:///util/Eval.rsc|(622,1030,<23,0>,<60,95>))
        at eval(|project://AutomatedPuzzleScript/src/PuzzleScript/Test/Engine/EvalExample.rsc|(288,36,<13,31>,<13,67>))
        at $root$(|prompt:///|(0,47,<1,0>,<1,47>)ok
rascal>
```

As far as I understand, the error happens when it tries to evaluate the dog constructor on the right side of the pattern. I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to make the environment available to the eval function without having to re-import everything in the eval. The reason I'm doing it this way is that I haven't found a way to dynamically generate abstract patterns, if there's a way I'd be glad to hear about it since it is the root of my current issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `eval` is not an often used function in Rascal; do you really need to dynamically create patterns?
- there is the node pattern: `(str name)()` which in this case would match any constructor with no arguments
- the real answer is that if you do `import` the right modules in the call to `eval` those modules will be cached by the interpreter which is used by the `eval` function
- so that would not be slow
- however, module reloading is not well-supported and you might have to restart the shell to get a fresh version into the eval evaluator.

Comment: I'm re-implementing a simple game engine that uses "rules" to rewrite part of a 2d level. Since I'm storing levels as a 3d matrix (row, columns and collision layers) I thought list matching would be the best for this, hence the need to be able to generate patterns.

For example, `[ RIGHT Player | Crate ]` becomes `[_*, moving_object("player", "right"), object("crate"), *_]`

I will try the other solutions you proposed, as they sound like they would fit, and report back. Thanks for your help as always.

Comment: Alright, keep us posted! Love that you are doing this.

Comment: In the end, I decided with importing the right modules before the call, caching everything I needed. I still need to optimise a few others things so I'm not completely sure of the impact on performance but it works very well. Thanks for the solution!